# Filter a view in Sharepoint Issue Tracking to find rows that haven't been assigned yet

Tags: sharepoint, view, filter, issue-tracking

Quick version: 
Is there a way to filter a view in the Sharepoint Issue Tracking module to find rows that do not have a value in a given column?

Detailed version:
At my workplace, we're using the Sharepoint Issue Tracking module to maintain our bug list. I want to create a view on the list to find the Issues that haven't been assigned to anyone yet.

So I: 
1. "Edit View"
2. in the "Filter" section, "Show the items when column", I select "Assigned To" from the columns drop-down list.
3. Then the problem. My best choice in the operator dropdown seems to be "is equal to". But then I don't know what to put in the value box. I tried leaving it empty, but that didn't work. It would be nice if there was an "is empty" choice in the operator dropdown, but there isn't.

Any constructive suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: you can also directly filter the column when you are looking at the contents of the list. Hope you already tried that option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked fine for me

> Filter - Assinged To Is Equal To (leave value box empty)

*(In the screenshot I also have Current is equal to Yes to show only Current Unassigned issues)*[image]

- If you've got more than one term in the filters are you using AND or OR?
- Why didn't it work (did it show everything including unassigned, or nothing)
- Can you post a screenshot of your view definition?

Comment: Awesome response--thanks for taking the time! The only other filter I had was "Status is equal to Open", which was and'ed with the Assigned To filter. When I removed the Status filter, you're right--the Assigned To with no value works. Thanks again.

Comment: For the benefit of others who might have a similar problem--the problem was that I had selected "Status" from the column pick list, and put "Open" in the value box. Returns no rows, because the correct value is "Active" (not "Open").